# Scala compare case class and get changed fields

Tags: scala

currently I use scalaz and shapeless to generate a case class which only updates changed values, however for some extended functionality I need to know which field (names) changed, is there a easy way to do it?

Or is there generally a better way to check every field for equality?

Example:

```
case class A(quanity: Option[Long], lose: Option[Long])

val a0 = A(Option(50), Option(10))
val a1 = A(Option(50), Option(20))

// Here it will be merged to a2 which is done by scalaz
// Now I need the fields that changed, ie. quanity or lose 
// (or any other field   if there are more
// a list or anything would be good enough:

val mergedList: List[String] = "lose" :: List()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind - productIterator:

```
    scala> A(5, "asd")
    res6: A = A(5,asd)

    scala> A(5, "asd")
    res7: A = A(5,asd)

    scala> A(1, "asd")
    res8: A = A(1,asd)

    scala> res6.productIterator.toList
    res9: List[Any] = List(5, asd)

    scala> res7.productIterator.toList
    res10: List[Any] = List(5, asd)

    scala> res8.productIterator.toList
    res11: List[Any] = List(1, asd)

    scala> res9 == res10
    res12: Boolean = true

    scala> res9 == res11
    res13: Boolean = false

    scala> res11.diff(res10)
    res18: List[Any] = List(1)
```

Comment: oh I think I wrote my question wrong, currently I need the named fields of the case class ie case class A(quanity: Option[Long], x: Option[Long]) I need "quanity" if quanity changed or "x" if x changed, however my case class is certainly bigger so I thought there is a easier way of doing so instead of doing a a.x == a.x or a.quanity = a.quanity